# Basic Python Programming Issue

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to this website so apologies if I have formatted my code wrong. I am having some trouble with my program; I want to have Player One able to re-enter their number if their first entry was greater than ten. My program seems to end after the first if statement.

Is there any particular statement I could use to get this job done?

Thanks.

```
#Program that gives Player2 five guesses to guess Player1's number.

import time

Number_To_Guess = int(input('Player One Enter Your Chosen Number: '))
if Number_To_Guess > 10:
    print('Your Number Must Be Less Than 10')
elif Number_To_Guess < 10:
    Player_Two_Guess = int(input('Player Two Guess The Number: '))

time.sleep(3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Program that gives Player2 five guesses to guess Player1's number.

This will work until user got right guess:

```
import time

Number_To_Guess = int(input('Player One Enter Your Chosen Number: '))
if Number_To_Guess > 10:
    print('Your Number Must Be Less Than 10')
elif Number_To_Guess < 10:
    Player_Two_Guess = 0
    TotalGuesses = 0
    while Player_Two_Guess != Number_To_Guess and TotalGuesses < 5:
        TotalGuesses += 1
        Player_Two_Guess = int(input('Player Two Guess The Number: '))
        time.sleep(3)
```

But i would reduce the sleep time :D
Added a counter to reduce the number of guesses to 5.

Comment: And when did Python have `&&` for logical and and `++` for post increment operators?

Comment: gee... that is what happens when jumping from language to language :D

Comment: hmm. not fair for voting down, as this is the only sample, that actually runs as desired allowing for multiple guesses :-/

Comment: @hexereisoftware you know it wasn't me who voted down right, I am very appreciative of your response? :)

Comment: @Virolite i know :) i think i know who did, but it is ok - i had a typing error in there for 20 mins which would have caused error

Comment: I did not downvote your answer. Don't think it was me

Comment: no no, i knew it was jon, and he was right in doing so, because i did not fix the typo right away, it was in there for more than 45 mins and was stupid from me but i was getting emotional 2 mins later :D

Answer (score 0):

An infinite loop will do the work:

```
while True:
    Number_To_Guess = int(input('Player One Enter Your Chosen Number: '))
    if Number_To_Guess > 10:
        print('Your Number Must Be Less Than 10')
    else:
        break
Player_Two_Guess = int(input('Player Two Guess The Number: '))
```

Comment: this will actually do an infinite loop on entering the number to guess but not for the guesses

Comment: Thnaks for your help.

Comment: @hexereisoftware See the break statement?

Comment: yes, but the line where player should guess number is not repeated, and to complete the "game" it should be repeated until `Player_Two_Guess` is equal to `Number_To_Guess`

Comment: you could just add `while Player_Two_Guess != Number_To_Guess:` before the last line, indent it and there you go

Comment: actually what both answers are missing now is a counter that counts up to 5 to allow only 5 guesses and no more :)

Comment: @hexereisoftware I'll add that in, I just needed assistance on the `Player_One_Guess` loop xD.

Comment: Python does not have a do-while loop. Bad :(